# What does "evanescent departures" in the text mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I looked up the dictionary, it described evanescent as vanishing, or passing away like vapor; and I knew departure is separation. Somehow I couldn't figure this sentence, and its relationship with the ocean.

> And, ah! his castle. The faery solitude of the place; with its turrets of misty blue, its courtyard, its spiked gate, his castle that lay on the very bosom of the sea with seabirds mewing about its attics, the casements opening on to the green and purple, **evanescent departures** of the ocean, cut off by the tide from land for half a day. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The castle apparently is situated at the tidal edge of the ocean on an island such that with every high tide the island is cut off from land.  Only at low tide can you walk out to the castle.

The evanescent departures of the ocean means it quickly fades from sight during the switch from the high tides to the low tides.  At low tide the water must leave quickly, leaving the tidal land exposed.  You can imagine the tide goes out 1/2 mile very quickly.